# How can I query on 3 tables using has-many-through relationship in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have searched too many posts but still confused. I don't wanna use **double** query to access **info**. I'm following that [example](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) which works well on just getting result without any condition but i wanna apply condition on **village** table\model as detailed below:

**Tables\Models Detail**

- **Province:**
  id, name ....
- **District:**
  id, name, province_id ....
- **Village:**
  id, name, status, district_id ....

**Edit**

1. **Province** has many **District**. (One-To-Many Relationship)
2. **District** has many **villages**. (One-To-Many Relationship)

Here **my question** is how **Province** can access **village
    info** using **has-many-through** Relationship on following criteria,

> Select **village data** where **district_id**=some_value and **status**=some_value.

Note: You might suggest any best.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You might want to add some more detail here, it is very unclear.  What are your 3 models?  What relationships have you defined between them?

Comment: Sir @dont-panic, I have edit and more refined whole question. now you may understand better.

Answer (score 1):

It is assumed that you have these **tables**

```
provinces
  -id
  -name

districts
  -id
  -name
  -province_id

villages
  -id
  -name
  -district_id 
  -status
```

```
class Province extends Model
{    
    public function villages(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Village','App\District');
    }
}
```

You can query as

```
$province = App\Province::find(1);         //Assumed id of province is 1
$province->villages;                       // Gives collection of villages
$villages->where('status','some_value')->where('district_id','some_district_val');   //Filters collection
```

Comment: Dear @Varun sharma, please read question again, i asked, where **district_id** and **status**. not only status.

Comment: Changed the code. Refer Laravel Collections for filtering data.